# Excel data validation using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way to set a data validation where the condition is, if the chosen cell is some string, its data validation is mapped to a specific column which is defined to be its data validation?
For example, lets say that if I choose some cell to be of type car ( can also be multiple cells) then its data validation will be the column {Toyota , Mazda, BMW) and if the cell is of type animal its data validation will be the column {dog , cat , elephant}.
And if so, is there a way to set that with python?
I know how to set a specific cell's data validation to be some column but I don't know how to make the data validation column but I don't know how to make it conditioned like in the example that I've showed above.

Comment: Excel has Macros that you can program in VBA. you can easily program this validations using macros. If such a solution exist why do you want it with python? Or you want to do the validation outside Excel?

Comment: Without VBA, I think the best option is as follows: create named ranges for the categories, e.g. `car` with ref: `{"Toyota","Mazda","BMW"}`. Create another one, `Options` with ref: `{"car","animal"}`. Now create a data validation (dv) for e.g. `A1` (`Allow: "list", Source: "=Options"`). Then, for `B1` create another dv (`Allow: "list", Source: "=INDIRECT(A1)"`). The dv for `B1` will now change based on the selection in `A1`. Let me know if you experience any difficulties implementing this logic using `openpyxl`. Surely, it can be done.

Comment: Oh, I'm giving the impression here that the named ranges can refer to arrays. This is not true: the dvs will not accept array refs. The refs need to be to actual ranges, containing the values.

Comment: It's often easier to set up what you want in Excel and look at the source code of the worksheet. NB. for a while now Excel has defaulted to using extensions for some validations.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Function to validate a column
def validate_column(df, column_name, enum_values):
    # Check for non-null values
    non_null_mask = df[column_name].notnull()
    non_null_failures = df[~non_null_mask]['Unique_Id']
    
    # Check for enum value validation
    enum_failures = df[~df[column_name].isin(enum_values)]['Unique_Id']
    
    return non_null_failures, enum_failures

# Read the data from the CSV file
data_file = "data.csv"  # Replace with your data file path
df = pd.read_csv(data_file)

# Create a dictionary to store enum values for each column
enum_files = {
    'column1': 'enum1.csv',
    'column2': 'enum2.csv',
    # Add more columns and enum files here
}

# Initialize lists to store failed validations
non_null_failures = []
enum_failures = []

# Iterate through columns and validate
for column_name, enum_file in enum_files.items():
    enum_values = pd.read_csv(enum_file)[column_name].tolist()
    non_null, enum = validate_column(df, column_name, enum_values)
    non_null_failures.extend(non_null)
    enum_failures.extend(enum)

# Remove duplicates from the failure lists
non_null_failures = list(set(non_null_failures))
enum_failures = list(set(enum_failures))

# Print the results
print("Unique Ids with non-null failures:", non_null_failures)
print("Columns with enum value failures:", enum_failures)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).